# Must one always use PROTECT when calling a function returning a SEXP?

Tags: c, r

I'm writing my first package integrating some C code (not `Rcpp`).

Assume I have an auxiliary function

```
SEXP f(double x){
  ...
  ...
}
```

Now I call this function in another one. Should I use `PROTECT`? That is, should I do

```
SEXP result_f;
PROTECT(result_f = f(x));
UNPROTECT(1);
```

Or is it correct to just do `SEXP result_f = f(x);`?

Comment: Ok @李哲源 thank you. (I use `PROTECT(result_f = f(x))` in my code and it works too.)

Comment: @李哲源 I saw this way in several tuto, like [this one](http://faculty.washington.edu/kenrice/sisg-adv/sisg-07.pdf) for example: `PROTECT(z = allocVector(REALSXP, m+n-1))`